# PROBLEM>> The Profile Redirect URL is Limited to One Setting for Multilingual Site

Tags: profile, urls, redirect

I have not found a solution to this as of yet and I scoured through here first with no answers.  Anyways, I have a multilingual Wordpress website (www.gcmf.ca) using the WPML plugin to manage between English (default) and French.  I am using CiviCRM profile forms to "walk" the logged in members through a renewal process. When they fill out the first page and click the Save button, it redirects them to the next page to fill out.  This works beautifully for English!

The problem happens when French is selected and they save the form. Since there can only be one URL entered in that Advanced field, it takes them to the next page, but it's in English.  They have to manually select French again. The path for English looks something like… “https://gcmf.ca/some-web-page/” and for French… “https://gcmf.ca/fr/some-web-page/”.  So you can see my dilemma.

Does anyone have ANY suggestions?  I'm going to  ask the users over at WPML to see if a language can be set by other means rather than using a language specifier in the URL.  That could solve the problem.  Also, from the CiviCRM side, I am wondering if there is a work around even if it involves a little code behind.  I am not a PHP programmer though and my skills in that area are very limited.

Ideally for the future, a nice feature would be to allow multiple values for the two redirect fields based on the language just like you can for the individual profile field labels and help text.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Kindly,
Rick Monyer

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with WPML, but what I normally do with multilingual sites is that I add one profile per language, that way you can also create the field labels as you want.

That way you can set the redirect URL as you want.

In WordPress you can then use a different shortcode per language to embed the profiles.